# How to create displacement vectors in QGIS using GPS points with different dates?

Tags: qgis, vector, gps, plugins

Is there a way to calculate and visualize displacement vectors in QGIS ? I have DGPS points taken at the same place (ground control points), but their position moved over time as they are located on a landslide.

[image]

Comment: Time Manager? https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/timemanager/

Comment: Timemanager is too limited. It focus on on animation, whereas I want to create a new vector based on the calculated displacement. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Event Layer Plugin? https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/event_layer/

Comment: If found most suitable up to now Points to Paths http://spatialgalaxy.net/2011/12/30/qgis-plugin-of-the-week-points-to-paths/
I created an extra column "Mission Id" for the Point order field. The Output is a vector between the points of the same Id, on which I can calculate its length by "vector geometry" The disadvantage is that it only shows 2D displacements, whereas we have 3D DGPS data. Someone who knows a tool for 3D displacement calculation ?

Answer (score 1):

The function **Points to Path** "converts a point layer to a line layer by joining points in a defined order".
It is located in the QGIS processing toolbox > Vector creation menu. (QGIS 3.2).

[image]